# How to implement \ifxcase: case equivalent of \ifx

Tags: math-mode, macros, comparison

I am looking for a case equivalent of `\ifx`. So, when I have nested uses of `\ifx` it would be cleaner to specify it in some sort of syntax similar to:

```
\newcommand*{\ColorSymbol}[1]{%
    \ifxcase#1{%
        {\exists}{\color{red}#1}%
        {\ge}{\mathrel{\color{orange}#1}}%
        {\le}{\mathrel{\color{blue}#1}}%
    }[#1\footnote{Unknown symbol: \string#1}]%
}%
```

instead of nesting `\ifx`s as is done in the MWE.

### Notes:

- Don't require the syntax to be identical to that, just something easier to read than the MWE.

### MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand*{\ColorSymbol}[1]{%
    \ifx#1\exists
        {\color{red}#1}%
    \else
        \ifx#1\ge
            \mathrel{\color{orange}#1}%
        \else
             \ifx#1\le
                \mathrel{\color{blue}#1}%
            \else
                #1%
                \footnote{Unknown symbol: \string#1}%
           \fi
       \fi
    \fi
}%


%%% Would prefer some case like syntax:
%\newcommand*{\ColorSymbol}[1]{%
%    \ifxcase#1{%
%        {\exists}{\color{red}#1}%
%        {\ge}{\mathrel{\color{orange}#1}}%
%        {\le}{\mathrel{\color{blue}#1}}%
%    }[#1\footnote{Unknown symbol: \string#1}]%
%}%



\begin{document}

$\ColorSymbol\exists x$

$A \ColorSymbol= B$

$a \ColorSymbol\ge n$,
$x \ColorSymbol\le z$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'd use a different syntax (a hash table lookup rather than a nested switch) that allows the coloured symbols to be declared separately, potentially at different points in the code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand*{\ColorSymbol}[1]{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname CS-\string#1\endcsname\relax
  #1\footnote{Unknown symbol: \string#1}%
  \else
  \csname CS-\string#1\expandafter\endcsname
  \fi}

\newcommand\defColorSymbol[3][]{%
    \expandafter\def\csname CS-\string#2\endcsname{%
    #1{\color{#3}#2}}}

\defColorSymbol\exists{red}
\defColorSymbol[\mathrel]\ge{orange}
\defColorSymbol[\mathrel]\le{blue}



\begin{document}

$\ColorSymbol\exists x$

$A \ColorSymbol= B$

$a \ColorSymbol\ge n$,
$x \ColorSymbol\le z$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting. Hadn't thought about that.

Answer (score 12):

You're loading `xstring` that already provides the feature:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\ColorSymbol}[1]{%
  \IfStrEqCase*{#1}{%
    {\exists}{\textcolor{red}{#1}}%
    {\ge}{\mathrel{\textcolor{orange}{#1}}}%
    {\le}{\mathrel{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}}%
  }[#1\footnote{Unknown symbol: \string#1}]%
}

\begin{document}

$\ColorSymbol\exists x$

$A \ColorSymbol= B$

$a \ColorSymbol\ge n$,

$x \ColorSymbol\le z$

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `xparse` it's similar:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\ColorSymbol}{m}
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    {\exists}{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
    {\ge}{\mathrel{\textcolor{orange}{#1}}}
    {\le}{\mathrel{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}}
   }
   {#1\footnote{Unknown symbol: \string#1}}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\ColorSymbol\exists x$

$A \ColorSymbol= B$

$a \ColorSymbol\ge n$,

$x \ColorSymbol\le z$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes that is what I have been doing, but I thought `\ifx` was the correct way to compare macros as per [How to test if two macros have identical definition](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285548/how-to-test-if-two-macros-have-identical-definition/).

Comment: @PeterGrill One could implement an `\ifx` based comparison along those lines. I'm not seeing particular benefits. I'll ask for a `\token_case:NNTF` function.

Answer (score 5):

Yet another option, here's an approach *loosely* based on `C` syntax.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
    \newcommand\switch[3][\ifx]{%provide switch-case structure with an if
        \def\@parsed@ifs{}%contains the arguments recast to standard \if\else\fi
        \def\@allfis{}%contains all of the \fis
        \def\case@with@option[##1]##2##3{%process a case with optional relation ##1
            \g@addto@macro\@allfis{\fi}%
            \g@addto@macro\@parsed@ifs{#1#2##1##2##3\else}}%            
        \def\case{\@ifnextchar[{\case@with@option}{\case@with@option[]}}%
        \def\default##1{\g@addto@macro\@parsed@ifs{##1}}%
        #3\expandafter\@parsed@ifs\@allfis%
    }
\makeatother

%%% Would prefer some case like syntax:
\newcommand*{\ColorSymbol}[1]{%
    \switch{#1}{%
        \case{\exists}{{\color{red}#1}}%
        \case{\ge}{\mathrel{\color{orange}#1}}%
        \case{\le}{\mathrel{\color{blue}#1}}%
        \default{#1\footnote{Unknown symbol: \string#1}}}
}%

\begin{document}

$\ColorSymbol\exists x$

$A \ColorSymbol= B$

$a \ColorSymbol\ge n$,
$x \ColorSymbol\le z$

\end{document}
```

[image: obligatory result image]

The conditional is left as an option (`\if`, `\ifx`, `\ifnum`, and `\ifdim` all work). To support those using a relation, `\case` is defined with an optional parameter. For example, `two` is the result from:

```
\def\testnumber{2}%
\def\anothernumber{5}%
\switch[\ifnum]{\testnumber}{%
    \case[=]{0}{zero}%
    \case[=]{1}{one}%
    \case[=]{2}{two}%
    \case[=]{\anothernumber}{another number}%
    \default{not 0, 1, or 2}}
```

Obviously this will fail spectacularly if `\case` or `\default` are defined elsewhere and used as arguments in the `\case` and `\default` statements (e.g., `\case{\exists}{\default\case}`). For the same reason, nesting `\switch` calls would be problematic as well. As such, this approach is limited.

Answer (score 4):

Something with a slightly different syntax (I feel I already had an answer on this site quite like an  `\ifxcase` but I can't find it now ...)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\long\def\xintdothis #1#2\xintorthat #3{\fi #1}%
\makeatletter
    \let\xintorthat \@firstofone
\makeatother
\newcommand*{\ColorSymbol}[1]{%
    \ifx#1+\xintdothis{\mathbin{\color{red}+}}\fi
    \ifx#1\ge\xintdothis{\mathrel{\color{orange}\ge}}\fi
    \ifx#1\le\xintdothis{\mathrel{\color{blue}\le}}\fi
    \xintorthat{#1\footnote{Unknown symbol: \string#1}}%
}%
\begin{document}
$a\ColorSymbol+ b$, $a\ColorSymbol\ge b$, $a\ColorSymbol\le b$, $a\ColorSymbol\infty b$
\end{document}
```

Comment: The expandable `\eqifcase` is discussed in [an answer by @wipet](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/179356/4686) and also an [answer of mine](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/179403/4686)

Comment: This has a grouping issue: Try `$a \ColorSymbol+ b` where the `b` is not supposed to have the color applied.

Comment: I copied the example code without further ado ;-) ... ok will add one brace level in the `+` case.

Comment: forgot to explicitly mention to the passer by that this is expandable, although in this context that doesn't mean anything really useful, but could be useful in other contexts where one wants expandability.