# Check for equality of boxes

Tags: boxes, sourcecode

Is there any way to check for what the contents of a box are? I see that there's a way to check if it's void, and what type of box it is, but can you check what's in it?

I'm working on a reflowing scheme for double column paragraphed footnotes, and my approach is to reflow the box every time a footnote is added. This has the side effect of reflowing the hyphens at the end of a hyphenated line. So I'm looking for a way to check if the `\lastbox` on a line is a hyphen, and remove it if it is.

An MWE could be produced if deemed necessary, but the direct question shouldn't need one.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/146166/10038

Comment: No, there isn't a method. By the way, a character such as the hyphen doesn't make a box that can be retrieved by `\lastbox`.

Comment: yes if luatex no for classic tex and xetex.

Comment: As @egreg say, “classic TeXs” (including pdf[e]TeX) provide no means to inspect programmatically, in full generality, the contents of a box register; yet, some kinds of manipulations *are* possible, even some subtle, and entirely non-obvious, ones.  So, it may be the case that your original intent (which you do not describe) isn’t doomed to failure: for example, look at pages 392–399 of _The TeXbook_ (Appendix D, section 7: _Paragraphs maneuvers_) for inspiration about how to play some really nasty tricks…